# javascript coding error, how do i fix it

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload=init;

function init(){
  var passwordPrompt = prompt("What is the password?");
  var passwordPrompt2 = prompt("Im sorry that was incorrect, please try again");
  if(passwordPrompt!="1234"){
    passwordPrompt2;
  }
if(passwordPrompt2!="1234"){
    passwordPrompt2
}
}
*This code is linked to an html doc*
```

When i enter "1234" it says its incorrect and once it goes to `prompt2`no matter what you enter it accepts and goes to the webpage instead of running again

Comment: Well, you are executing both prompts after each other. `passwordPrompt2` refers to the value that was provided by the user in the second prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You're prompting for the password a second time immediately, before you even test what input the user provided.

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
function init(){
  var passwordPrompt = prompt("What is the password?");
  while(passwordPrompt!="1234") {
     passwordPrompt = prompt("Im sorry that was incorrect, please try again");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Justin I'm glad I could help. If this or any other answer resolved your issue, you should consider accepting the answer that was most correct and complete. This indicates to other users that the issue has been resolved, and it helps anyone that might encounter the same issue know that the answer may help them as well. You can also upvote any answer you found useful. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are executing both the prompts one after the other which is creating the problem.

Try like this:

```
function init(){
  var passwordPrompt = prompt("What is the password?");
  while(passwordPrompt!="1234") {
     passwordPrompt = prompt("Im sorry that was incorrect, please try again");
  }
}
```